# Can't get y-axis on matplotlib histogram to display the right numbers

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

So I have this simple DataFrame which i am trying to plot a histogram with

```
    Hour    Count   Average Count
2      6       4         0.129032
4      7       1         0.032258
1     12       9         0.290323
3     16       3         0.096774
0     20    2022        65.225806
```

What I want is the Hour to be on the x-axis and Average Count to be on the Y axis. But when i tried this:

```
fig, hour = plt.subplots(1, 1)
hour.hist(test.Hour)
hour.set_xlabel('Time in 24 Hours')
hour.set_ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

I got this instead. I have tried doing `test.Count` and `test['Average Count']` but both only affects the x-axis

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?
'df' is the name of the dataframe.

```
df.plot(x='Hour', y = 'Averag Count', kind='bar')
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: How about now? If this is also not what you are looking for, put a pic showing approximately what you are looking for.

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: If the answer helped consider up-voting & accepting it (else others may think it is still open).